# Сайт конструктор

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, есть желание создать сайт "Онлайн конструктор для создание сайтов" типа [jimdo](http://www.jimdo.com/l/s/main/ru/1/?gclid=CN7wqIeVjbYCFfB3cAodmSEAIQ#ref=a927587) и есть несколько вопросов:
Каждый созданный сайт создаются как обычный аккаунт (например как в обычных блогах только с большим преимуществом редактирование дизайна и добавлять модули) с таким урл:

`mysite.ru/?id=4214&name=youname`

его преобразуем в ЧПУ `youname.mysite.ru` и вот вопрос как быть если клиент захочет домен 2го уровня, можно ли ссылку `mysite.ru/?id=4214&name=youname` показать как yousite.ru или создать отдельную директорию для его домена и туда импортировать в phphtml код, чтоб вообще отдельно уже работал не зависимо от моего сайта?
Что еще можете предложить, у кого есть опыты поделитесь пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы предоставить пользователю домен второго уровня, необходимы услуги регистратора доменных имён и хостера. Автоматизировать этот процесс не получится (если только вы не являетесь хостером и регистратором доменных имён или у вас заключён с ними какой-то договор на подобный случай). Но скорее всего вы ни тем, ни другим не являетесь, и договора у вас нет, поэтому пользователю придётся зарегистрировать доменное имя и найти хостинг самомтоятельно. Единственное, что вы сможете сделать - это выдать ему весь его контент и движок вашего сайта, чтобы пользователь смог развернуть его на своём новом домене.